# First comment posted(appended) always remains on top

Tags: jquery, ajax, append

I will try to describe my problem as accurate as I can and what I did in trying to fix it before asking for help here. 
The script Im using appends new comments via ajax. It works but like any other script.. has its problems. On my website I've set to display newst comments first.

So, first comment posted - appended at the top.

Second comment posted (without refreshing the page) should be appended on top of the first, instead it is appended under the first one, and it goes on like this with third posted under second and fourth under third...

http://s8.postimg.org/407uhljl1/image.jpg

This is where the magic happen
http://pastebin.com/5nFeEpZg

To be more exactly here :

```
  var the_parent_class = jQuery('#'+css_respond).parent().attr('class');

if(typeof the_parent_class != "undefined" && the_parent_class.search(/depth-/i) 

  != -1) { //threaded

   // Check if there are already replies, if not, add <ul class="children">

  if(jQuery('#'+css_respond).parent().children('.children').length) {

  // There are replies, add comment to the end of the list
   jQuery('#'+css_respond).parent().children('.children').append(tmpComment);

   } else {
   // First reply
  tmpComment = '<ul class="children">'+tmpComment+'</ul>';

  jQuery('#'+css_respond).parent().append(tmpComment) }

  else 
  {
 // Normal comment
  if(commentPosition == 'bottom') {

  jQuery('.'+css_commentlist).append(tmpComment);

  } 

  else if(commentPosition == 'top') 

  {
  jQuery('.'+css_commentlist).prepend(tmpComment);

  } 

  else {

  jQuery('.'+css_commentlist).append(tmpComment);

  }
  }
  } 
  else {

 // The commentlist doesn't exist, this is the first comment

 // Do we need to support the 'Content Press' Theme?

 if(compatContentPress == 'checked') {           

 jQuery('div.postbox').before(jQuery(tmpComment).find('div.boxcomments'));

                    } else {
  tmpComment = '<ol class="'+css_commentlist+'">'+tmpComment+'</ol>';

  jQuery('#'+css_respond).before(jQuery(tmpComment));
                    }
            }
```

When the page is refreshes comments appear like it should - latest posted first - so the problem must lie in appending the comments.

Before asking here I've tried to put a breakpoint on

```
   var the_parent_class = jQuery('#' + css_respond).parent().attr('class');
```

and at the same time switched commentPosition from 'bottom' to 'top' and top to bottom but nothing changed.

The script is called PTM Ajax Comments and I've downloaded it from the github repo.

```
    commentPosition = data.commentPosition;
commentPosition = data.commentPosition;
if(commentPosition == 'bottom') {
} else if(commentPosition == 'top') {
```

Comment: Could you include the line where you call the plugin in your own code? This is just the code from the plugin itself.

Comment: where do `commentPosition` get its value from?

Comment: Im not calling the plugin anywhere, it is a wp site(activated from plugins). are you reffering to this line ?  function PTM_AJAXComments_Init() { global $ptm_ajax_comments;   $ptm_ajax_comments = new PTM_AJAXComments(); } add_action("init", "PTM_AJAXComments_Init");

Comment: I'll post in my question

Comment: as a debugging option, change `commentPosition = data.commentPosition;` to `commentPosition = "top";` and let me know what happens?

Comment: I've tried and nothing changed

Comment: That fixed it. Im verry sorry. There we're two mention in 2 separated files of commentPosition = data.commentPosition; and I only changed one of them. now with both it works! Brilliant. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

not sure if i got youre code right but i think:

```
else {
   jQuery('.'+css_commentlist).append(tmpComment);
}
```

is suppose to be:

```
else  {
   jQuery('.'+css_commentlist).prepend(tmpComment);
}
```

almost at the bottom of the file

Comment: I don't think so - `commentPosition == 'bottom'` implies adding to the bottom to me.

Comment: the final 'else' is just a default. As such if this fixes the issue the OP should supply `commentPosition: 'top'` when he calls the plugin rather than adjusting the default as you have suggested.

Comment: i dont get why op do have append as the default becous when you read the qustion he states that prepend is the default behaviour, and reading the code it looks like only comment reply's are suppose to be appendet

Comment: I've tried that and the one before and combined and.. nothing